# Wake On Demand (Load Balanced Solutions ?)

Tags: networking, nas, wake-on-lan, load-balancer

I'm out of idea facing a challenging situation : *Wake up a server on demand*.

### The problem

Wake-up a physical server that listen on specific port, when an incoming packet arrives. 
There may be a controller/middleware between clients and the server, but it should not affect bandwidth (and transparent for users).

The main goal : saving power consumption.

### What I've tried

The setup I've tried for this demonstration is applied for a Samba NAS server.

---

- **preexec samba command**  ([Automatic WoL remote filesystem](https://serverfault.com/questions/389286/automatic-wake-on-lan-in-linux-when-accessing-remote-filesystem/389474#389474), [Transparent gateway for FileServer](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2265701)) : The goal of this solution is to expose a front NAS that accept all requests, and when a user want to access to a specific share, the preexec command will wake up the server with a custom script.

  [preexec topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUNtN.png)

  - PROS : Transparent for users in established state
  - CONS : Not generic, Bandwith affected

---

- **Firewall wake up** : similar to the previous option, but acting at transport layer regarding to the requested port the firewall will wake up the server. Requires a subnet for masquerading the server.

  [firewall topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Cv1.png)

  - PROS : Generic, Transparent for users in established state
  - CONS : Bandwith affected, Requires a new subnet

---

- **IPVS DR** : based on load-balanced environments, the goal is to take advantage of the floating IP address. I've imaginated to modify the ipvs stack ([ipvsadm](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ipvsadm) or [keepalived](https://www.keepalived.org/)) by implementing the wake-up server feature when a request arrives. That's a lot of works and searching, that's why I would prefer to see if there are another solutions ;)

  [IPVS DR topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOYfL.png)

  - PROS : Generic, Transparent for users in established state, Bandwith not affected
  - CONS : Hard to set up ?

---

This is an example with the NAS server, but I would prefer an elegant and generic solution to solve this problem.

Any ideas ? :)